# call API and save to mySQL

Tags: javascript, php

I have a script which gets my users data from Strava and builds a JSON.

I would like to get this data saved into my database without me needing to click submit on a form as this script I plan to run at set periods using a cronjob.

I have saved the data to local storage but then Im unable to get it out into PHP variables, I've tried passing the javascript variables to PHP variables but that doesn't work, if i'm not mistaken the PHP runs first the javascript so my PHP variables are empty when it inserts into the database table.

```
      var strava_data_object = { 'activity_date': activity_date,
                        'commute': commute,
                        'distance': distance,
                        'activity_id': activity_id,
                        'activity_type' : activity_type };

      // Put the object into storage
      localStorage.setItem('strava_data_object', JSON.stringify(strava_data_object));
```

To test my PHP INSERT I saved a copy of my JSON to 'JSON/strava_data.json' and then ran the following code it all works as planned

```
<?php
  //read the json file contents
  $jsondata = file_get_contents('JSON/strava_data.json');

  //convert json object to php associative array
  $decoded_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

  //convert json object to php associative array
  $distance = $decoded_data['distance'];
  $type = $decoded_data['activity_type'];
  $commute = $decoded_data['commute'];
  $date = $decoded_data['activity_date'];
  $activity_id = $decoded_data['activity_id'];

?>
```

Maybe if I could save my results to my JSON folder using javascript rather than to the local browser storage but I don't know if it can be done, and if it can how?

below is my function for getting the data from strava

```
function getActivites(res){
    const activities_link = `https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athlete/activities?access_token=${res.access_token}`;
    fetch(activities_link)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then(function (data){
      activity_type = data[0]['type'];
      // Check if Activity is Run, Walk or Cycle
      if (activity_type == 'Run' || activity_type == 'Cycle'  ||  activity_type == 'Walk' ){

      activity_date = data[0]['start_date'];
      activity_date = activity_date.slice(0,10);
      distance_detail = data[0]['distance'] * 0.000621371;
      distance = distance_detail.toFixed(2);
      activity_id = data[0]['id'];
      activity_name = data[0]['name'];
      activity_name = activity_name.toLowerCase();

      const  subString = "commute";
      if(activity_name.includes(`${subString}`))
      { commute = true; }
      else { commute = false; }

      var strava_data_object = { 'activity_date': activity_date,
                        'commute': commute,
                        'distance': distance,
                        'activity_id': activity_id,
                        'activity_type' : activity_type };

      // Currently saving the object into local storage
      localStorage.setItem('strava_data_object', JSON.stringify(strava_data_object));
       
    // Wondering if there is a way to save Save Json file to a folder

    }
    else{
      window.confirm("something went wrong, please check your last activty on strava was a Run, Walk or Cycle!");
    }
  }
    );
}
```

Comment: _"this script I plan to run at set periods using a cronjob"_ - in a cron context, you won't have any localStorage available to begin with. Or a user session.

Comment: or even a browser - unless you use headless Chrome.

Comment: If you can run a script to get data out of a system via cronjob, then you can probably write the full code in php, which would get the data from the source system and then insert it into your database. The question is totally unclear to me: we do not know how your data extraction script works.

Comment: @CBroe I have removed the session ID as thats not required, thank you for pointing out my oversight that using localStorage wont be an option. Is it possible to save it to a folder?

Comment: @Shadow Apologies for my lack of clarity as you can imagine i'm new to coding. I'm unsure what you mean by data extraction? I've added above my javascript function thats gets data for the user

Comment: You should be able to make that whole API request in PHP to begin with. Then you don't have to figure out how to get the data from client-side JavaScript to server-side PHP in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe makes sense especially as for saving data with Javascript keeps points me to node.js which I don't know but isn't that server side language like PHP

Comment: Yes, node.js is a server-side version of javascript. You can use both node.js and php to interact with the api and save the data into a database.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for your help was stuck on this for hours, Ive managed to make the API request with PHP as you suggested.